# Basic algebraic manipulation of statistical equation

Tags: statistics

I'm reading through some assigned text for a finance class I'm in and I'm having a hard time seeing how the equation

$
E(R_iM) = 1 = COV(R_i,M) + E(R_i)E(M)
$

is equivalent to

$
E(R_i) = \frac{1}{E(M)} - \frac{COV(R_i,M)}{E(M)}
$

My first thought was that the covariance was subtracted over and then the whole thing divided by E(M) but that would still leave the LHS as

$
E(R_i) - \frac{COV(R_i,M)}{E(M)}
$

Am I missing something or do I need to ask my professor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$1 = COV(R_i,M) + E(R_i)E(M)$$
Rearrange for
$$1-COV(R_i,M)=E(R_i)E(M)$$
And divide through by $E(M)$ to get $$
E(R_i) = \frac{1}{E(M)} - \frac{COV(R_i,M)}{E(M)}$$